# how can we compare array with array in array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example

```
var array1=['1','2','3','4'];
var array2=['1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3,6','1,7,8,9'];
```

Compare this two array.

I try this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j= 0; j< array2.length; j++) {
      if()
      --------
    }
}
```

Thank before hand

Comment: What result are you looking for ?

Comment: Your second array is not a multidimensional array if that is what you're saying in your question title. Is just a normal array of strings. Also, that is not `jQuery` is plain `JavaScript`. And comparing can mean multiple things...

Comment: what should be compared? what result do you expect and why?

Comment: if all elements in array 1 have in sub array of array 2 will show result match

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your question.  It's extremely difficult to understand what your question truly is.  Forcing people to make assumptions just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: sorry guy this is my first question for this blog. First time i use to ask a quetion

Comment: @happytola hi - welcome to SO - please take time to read the tour, including: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `join(',')` and `includes()` method .

**Updated**

1. Return with matching arguments
2. Use `Array#reduce` its help match each one of the `array1` arguments

```js
var array1 = ['1','2', '4'];
var array2 = ['1,2,3,4,5', '1,2,3,6', '1,7,8,9'];
var res = array2.reduce(function(a, b) {
  array1.forEach(function(val) {
    if (b.includes(val) && !a.includes(b)) {
      a.push(b);
    }
  })
  return a;
}, [])
console.log(res);
console.log(res.length > 0)
```

Comment: thank you very much it's work. But i want to ask a question. Why this script will show true or false??

Comment: it does not works if the pattern is somewhere in the string. you need to use indexOf and check against zero.

Comment: if i change var array1=['1','2','3']; the result will show false but it still in sub of array2

Comment: @happytola .Because `includes` function returns only Boolean .see my updated answer .I was added with find for matching arguments returns from array

Comment: @happytola, why can you use includes, but not arrow functions?

Comment: i don know but it still show error with this sign '=>'

Comment: @NinaScholz any help please

Comment: @prasad thank u very much it's work

Comment: @prasad if i change array like this:  var array1 = ['1', '2', '4'];
                var array2 = ['1,2,3,4,5', '1,2,3,6', '1,7,8,9']; it will return false. but it still in array2 can you fix this thank

Comment: @prasad any help please if we swap the range of array it will return false

Answer (score 2):

You could check each value of `array1` with any value of the splitted items of `array2`.

ES5

```js
var array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    array2 = ['1,2,3,4,5', '1,2,3,6', '1,7,8,9'],
    check = array2.some(function (c) {
        return array1.every(function (b) {
            return function (a, i) {
                return a === b[i];
            };
        }(c.split(',')));
    });
    
console.log(check);
```

ES6

```js
var array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    array2 = ['1,2,3,4,5', '1,2,3,6', '1,7,8,9'],
    check = array2.some(c => array1.every((b => (a, i) => a === b[i])(c.split(','))));
    
console.log(check);
```

Comment: sorry when i paste your script i got error with this sign =>

Comment: @happytola, why can you use includes, but not arrow functions?

Comment: @NinaScholz maybe it's another "error" - bit low on the details in the question.

Comment: Interesting. wasn't aware of some and every functions